# how to code simple minimax algorithm in C#?

Tags: recursion, foreach, tree, iteration, minimax

i want to build a simple tree and compare the child and recursive call, its like a  mini-max algorithm. compare the value of each node and return the child of root.

i have tried all the day and i cant code it right yet. if u have experience with mini-max algorithm please help me or if u have any source to learn about it please tell me.

can someone make an example code with 3 or more depth (iteration) based on this node ?

```
class node
{

    public int value;
    public int id;
    public List <node> child = new List <node>();   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: 
make global variable:

```
public node minNode;
public node maxNode;
```

create function :

```
public void Compare(node currentNode)
{
    if (minNode.value>currentNode.value)
    {
        minNode=currentNode;
    }
    if (maxNode.value<currentNode.value)
    {
        maxNode=currentNode;    
    }
    foreach(var currNode in currentNode.child)
    {
        Compare(currNode);
    }
}
```

and then in your code call it:

```
minNode=rootNode;
maxNode=rootNode;
Compare(rootNode);
```

And after that your will take max and min in this variable, where rootNode is your root node in a tree